# How to call static method using class property?

Tags: php, class, variables, properties, static-methods

There is a property $modelName in class A that is accessed in this class using $this->modelName.

This property contains a name of another class B.

I want to call a static method of class B not creating an object of B.

Working code:

```
$b = $this->modelName;
$b::model()->findAll();
```

Question:
How to call model()->findAll() not using $b?

I tried `$this->modelName::model()->findAll();` but it’s not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it:

```
 class A{
   public $modelName = 'B';

   function callB(){
     call_user_func(array($this->modelName, 'model'))->findAll();
   }
 }

 class B{
   private  static $model = null;

   static function model(){

     if (!self::$model) {
        self::$model = new B();
     }
     return self::$model;
  }

   function findAll(){
      print  __CLASS__.' method `findAll()`';
   }
 }

$A = new A;
$A->callB();

// B method `findAll()`
```

Comment: call_user_func(array($this->modelName, 'model'))->findAll(); — is the most acceptable variant.

But is there any way to call model() not using call_user_func()?

Comment: @tr_ thinking, in PHP its only  one way to do what u need - `$this->modelName::model()->findAll();` like I showed

Comment: @tr_ also, u can use `call_user_func_array`  to call with params array

Comment: Ok, thank you for quick reply. If there is no other way I'll be using your answer.